# How to instruct internal function to evaluate arguments only after numerical values are plugged in?

Tags: evaluation, hold

For convenience, let me start with a simple example. The following code calculates the sorted eigenvalues of a 4x4 Hermitian matrix with a parameter `x`

```
eigen[x_] := 
 Sort[Eigenvalues[(1 - x^2) KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[3], 
      PauliMatrix[0]] + 
    Cos[x] KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[3]] + 
    KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[3]] + 
    3 Sin[x] KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1]]]]
```

If I call `eigen` with a numerical value, say `1.0`, then everything works fine. But if I call `eigen` as `eigen[x]`, the `Sort` function won't be able to correctly sort the eigenvalues. For example, on my machine, `eigen[x] /. {x -> 1.0}` returns `{-1.61733, 1.61733, -3.56559, 3.56559}`.

I want to minimize the difference between the third smallest eigenvalue and the second smallest eigenvalue, so I write `FindMinimum[eigen[x][[3]]-eigen[x][[2]], {x, 1.0}]`. However, it seems that `FindMinimum` will try to evaluate the first argument with the symbol `x` such that the eigenvalues are not correctly sorted.

Is there a way that I can instruct the internal function (e.g., `FindMinimum`) to leave the first argument unevaluated? I notice that `FindMinimum` already have `HoldAll` attribute but still tries to manipulate the symbolic expression.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037) already?

Comment: @J.M.'sennui I haven't, but I already played with `NumericQ` a bit. If I define the function as `eigen[x_?NumericQ]:=...`, `eigen[x][[1]]` will be evaluated to `x`, which is clearly not what I want.

Comment: With the definition `eigen[x_?NumericQ]:=...`, `eigen[x]` returns unevaluated, so `eigen[x][[1]]` is the argument of the unevaluated function. You use the function as before, i.e., `eigen[1.]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eigen[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Sort[Eigenvalues[(1 - x^2) KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[3], 
      PauliMatrix[0]] + 
    Cos[x] KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[3]] + 
    KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[3]] + 
    3 Sin[x] KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1]]]]
```

Use a helper function to evaluate `eigen`

```
dif[x_?NumericQ] := Module[{lst = eigen[x]}, lst[[3]] - lst[[1]]]

{min, arg} = FindMinimum[dif[x], {x, 1.0}]

(* {3.4641, {x -> -1.29913*10^-8}} *)
```